# using a sum to give a formula for the nth prime.

Tags: number-theory

$\bf{Problem (a) }$

Let $p_n $ denote the nth prime.

Show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{p_n}{10^{2^n}} $ converges.

we know that $ p_n \leq 4^n $ by chebychev  additionally $4^n \leq 4^{2^{n}} $ so we have that  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{p_n}{10^{2^n}}\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{4}{10})^{2^{n}} $ by ratio test we have that $\frac{(\frac{4}{10})^{2^{n+1}}}{(\frac{4}{10})^{2^{n}} } = (\frac{4}{10})^2 <1$ so the series converges by ratio test.

$\bf{Problem (b) }$

let $\alpha =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{p_n}{10^{2^n}} $ show that $p_n = \lfloor 10^{2^n} \alpha \rfloor - 10^{2^{n-1}} \lfloor 10^{2^{n-1}} \alpha \rfloor$

It gives the following hint; Prove $0 < 10^{2^n}\sum_{m=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{p_m}{10^{2^m}}<1$ but im not really sure how this applies but i think its a fascinating result as it givens the nth prime i am assuming we have no idea what $\alpha$ is?

Comment: Following the hint, you may just show the formula from $10^{2^n} \sum_{m=1}^n \frac{p_m}{10^{2^m}}$. In my opinion, this is not a fascinating result at all, because the definition of the number itself requires knowing primes $p_n$.

Comment: sorry i dont follow we cant use $\alpha$ to find the nth prime?

Comment: We need to know every single $p_n$'s to construct the number $\alpha$, there is no point in using $\alpha$ to find the $n$th prime.

Comment: The idea for this problem is that someone is trying to make a decimal that encodes all the primes. The part (b) of the problem is asking you to show how the decimal expression of the infinite series gives you the primes back.

That is why @i707107 said it was not an interesting result, because you can probably do similar "trick" for any sequence of numbers by making the powers of the $10$ grow sufficiently fast.